# How to best follow a function to understand what it is doing?

Tags: c++, algorithm, refactoring, pseudocode

This question is general but I am going to give a specific example.

The specific problem that needs to be solved is explained [here](http://codeforces.com/contest/156/problem/A). The description is long so I will not cut and paste but the basic idea is for input strings S and T (as they are called in the code below), find the minimum number of changes that needs to be done to S to produce T. One change can be :

- Insert one letter to any end of the string.
- Delete one letter from any end of the string.
- Change one letter into any other one.

Below is a solution I am trying to track. What I am looking for are tips on how to best grok the solution. What are some methods I can use to read and understand the code (let's discard stepping through a debugger).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
char S[2010];
char T[2010];
int lens,lent;
int main()
{
    int i,j,ma,p;

    while(scanf("%s%s",S,T)!=EOF)
    {
        lens=strlen(S);
        lent=strlen(T);
        ma=0;p=0;
        for(i=0;i<lens;i++)
        {
            p=0;
            for(j=0;j<lent;j++)
            {
                if(i+j>=lens)
                    break;
                if(S[i+j]==T[j]){p++;}
            }
            if(ma<p)
                ma=p;
            if(ma==lent)
                break;
        }
        for(i=0;i<lent;i++)
        {
            p=0;
            for(j=0;j<lens;j++)
            {
                if(i+j>=lent)
                    break;
                if(T[i+j]==S[j]){p++;}
            }
            if(ma<p)
                ma=p;
            if(ma==lent)
                break;
        }
        printf("%d\n",lent-ma);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whoever wrote that function should be fired and never allowed near a programming language again. Throw it out and start over, and use real variable names and comments. There's no easy way to figure out what this is doing, how it's doing it, or even *why it was written*. Voted to close as you've rejected out of hand the only real solution, **step through a dubugger**.

Comment: Saying "let's discard stepping through a debugger" for this question is like asking someone to skydive without a parachute... especially with this program. (Please refer to meagar's comment above)

Comment: @meagar, you are to harsh. this code is surely not the best, but recently I found two sources in the area of jpeg processing with most ugly codes. Both authors are now holding a chair in IT

Comment: Have you think in the "universal debugging method", that is printing to the console?

Comment: @meagar Well if there are comments already explaining what the code is doing than there is no need for the question, no?

Comment: @meagar: Maybe you're not used to reading C code. It's not uncommon for C programmers to be concise like that. I'm not saying that this particular code is the most beautiful thing I've ever seen, but using `i` and `j` for indices in nested loops is very common. You also have `lens` and `lent` (length of `s` and length of `t`). `p` is a position, and `ma` a `maximum` (not called `max` to avoid clashes with the function of the same name). So it's not *that* bad.

Comment: Concise code is good. Cryptic code is bad. There is a difference. And this isn't C, it's C++, and *awful* C++ at that.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe You got it wrong. `p` is not a position. `p` is the amount of characters in the currently investigated substring which match their corresponding character in the "goal" string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1: Explain to yourself what the variables represent:**

`S`: the string from which we want to extract a substring

`T`: the string which we want to achieve in the end, after having modified the extracted substring with as few operations as possible

`lens`: length of string S

`lent`: length of string T

`i`: the index in S from which the extracted substring starts

`j`: the index in string T of a character which we want to match with a corresponding character in the substring

`p`: the amount of matching chars found for the currently investigated substring

`ma` : the maximum amount of matching chars for any of the substrings

---

**Step 2: Having established these meanings, it's rather simple to translate the first loop into words:**

```
for loop 1 :    selects a start position of the substring

    set the match counter to 0, since we start investigation of a new substring


    for loop 2 :    loops through the substring

        if 1 :      if there is no char left to read string S, stop looping

        if 2 :      if the current character in the extracted substring matches
                a character in the "goal" string, increment the match counter (p)


    if 3 :      now, we finished looping through a substring,
            if the count of matching characters in the substring and the goal
            string was higher than for any of the previous counts,
            then store this value as the max count

    if 4 :      if the max count of matching characters is equal to the 
            length of the "goal string", dr Moriatry can receive the goal string
            with 0 substring changes, and hence, we can stop looping
```

---

The next loop is similar. The roles of S and T have kind of been reversed. Notice though, that the roles of S and T have not been fully reversed (as some people have said). The end condition for the outer for loop uses the length of T in both cases, which makes sense.

Here we extract substrings from string T (the "goal" string) and try to match them against string S. Why are we doing this?

I expect that the person who wrote the code wanted to account for cases like the following, e.g.:

```
S = "b"     T = "abc"
```

If we'd only extract substrings from S and match them against the whole T string, starting at the first index (like the first loop does), we'd only compare "does `b` (in S) match `a` (the first char in T) and then we'd go on and say: "Since no substring matches, we need 3 string change operations to receive string T" (which is obviously wrong, as we can achieve it by choosing "b" as the substring to extract, and making 2 change operations to end up with T)

Answer (score 2):

The best solution will be to rewrite the code as you are understanding it. There are few things :

1. Watch for duplicate code. He does the same thing with S and T, and the roles are reversed. You can create a function `foo()` with both strings as parameter and use
   `foo(S,T)` and `foo(T,S)`
2. Try to break too much depth. When you see lot of nested loops most of the time some of the inner loops can be seen as a function doing something specific.
3. rename progressively the variables as you are understanding more what is happening
4. Last but not least, ***don't discard stepping through the debugger***

Answer (score 2):

The key to understanding the code is to understand the meaning of the variables that change least, in this case, ma and p and to recognize coding idioms.

The two code snippets

```
if(ma<p)
    ma=p;
if(ma==lent)
    break;
```

are a "high water mark" idiom for the variable p (with a break condition on the maximum possible value). p is incremented whenever there is match in the character at the j position of the LHS substring starting at i with the j position character of the RHS. So for the loops indexed by j (the inner loops), p is the number of identical characters that are at the same j positions. So I would rename p (in my head at least!) to "number_of_identical_chars_in_same_pos".

The loops indexed by i find the highest p (saved in ma) for each substring in the LHS that ends with the last character of the LHS (or earlier if the substring is lent long). So ma should be renamed "max_common_chars_in_a_span". Together the two loops find the maximum number of common characters in the same position of any substring ending with the last character of either side.

The final step (left to the serious student) is to understand how this solves the problem and that's mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by first doing some string manipulation on the program. First step would be to try to give better names to the variables.

I'd replace 'i' with sPos for the position in string S. Well, at least that applies for the first loop, for the second loop 'i' changes meaning to be the position in T, so I'd actually then decide to get rid of i and instead have two variables, so each variable has one purpose which matches its name.

Then try the same for j, ma and p.

Once that's done, I would consider trying to work out what the two 'for' loops do. They seem virtually identical. Maybe they could be split out into one function that gets called twice. Again, try to work out what this function does and name it very carefully so the name explains its purpose.

Repeat steps like this until you've got some code that makes some human sense.

Comment: So what you are saying is that your method is to first start by editing the code to make it more descriptive? Then, to understand the loop, do you do it in your head? Pen and paper? repl?

Comment: To work out what the loop does, I'd first have to understand what the purpose of the variables within them are. After that, I might be able to make the logical step in my head, or I may have to pull out the pen and paper and work through a simple example in my head... in effect step through the code in my head (or on paper). By doing so, I'd hope to discover the gist of what is going on.

Comment: Try giving T the value "abc" and S the value "adcf" or something like that (so there are some similar letters, some different, some different positions, and different length strings). And run through the code. Point a finger at the line you're executing, and use a piece of paper (or space next to the code) and write down the values of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

1. Extract the two outer loops into their own functions.
2. Find the commonality (hint: they are only modifying `ma`).
3. Extract that commonality.
4. Extract the inner loops to their own function (hint: the code is identical).
5. Write unit tests for each function to test your understanding.

Comment: This could be an awesome refactoring screencast.